# error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [][]' to 'int' and error C2087: missing subscript

Tags: c++

for a brief description; I tried to make a 5*3 matrix, to get values from a user (in the main method, moreover; in the other methods, I was trying to do some calculations to easily get a result for the 2D array, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int All_Matrix_sum( int, int, int);
int Diag_Matrix_sum( int, int, int);

int main (){
    int My_Matrix[5][3];
    for(int i=0; i <5 ; i++){
        for (int y=0; y <3; y++){
            cout << "Please enter the Value corresponds to the position of " << i << ", " << y << endl;
            cin >> My_Matrix[i][y]; // get values from the user
            }
        }
    cout << "the sumation of all the matrix elements is : " << All_Matrix_sum(My_Matrix, 5 , 3 );
    cout << "the sumation of the matrix's diagonal is : "<<   Diag_Matrix_sum(My_Matrix, 5 , 3 );
}



int Diag_Matrix_sum(int Matrix[][], int rows, int columns){ // this method calculates the sumation of the diagonal elements
    int sumD=0;
    for(int Row_numbers=0; Row_numbers <rows; Row_numbers++){
        for (int Column_numbers=0; Column_numbers <columns; Column_numbers++){
            if(Column_numbers==Row_numbers)
            sumD += Matrix[Row_numbers][Column_numbers];        
            }
        }
    return sumD;
}


int All_Matrix_sum(int Matrix[][], int rows, int columns){ // this method calculates the sumation of all the elements in such a matrix
    int sumA=0;
    for(int Row_numbers=0; Row_numbers <rows; Row_numbers++){
        for (int Column_numbers=0; Column_numbers <columns; Column_numbers++){
            sumA += Matrix[Row_numbers][Column_numbers];        
            }
        }
    return sumA;
}
```

Whenever i compile, the following errors are presented:

```
error C2664: 'All_Matrix_sum' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [5][3]' to 'int'
There is no context in which this conversion is possible.
'Diag_Matrix_sum' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [5][3]' to 'int'
There is no context in which this conversion is possible
error C2087: 'Matrix' : missing subscript
error C2087: 'Matrix' : missing subscript
```

Comment: Your declared prototypes don't match the defined functions' prototypes, and you can only "leave out" the first dimension of the parameters. (An array is not a pointer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int Diag_Matrix_sum(int Matrix[][], int rows, int columns){` is illegal. A C-style array declarator must specify all dimensions except the innermost.

Another problem is that the definition of `Diag_Matrix_sum` does not match the prototype.

One way to fix this would be to write:

```
template<int rows, int columns>
int Diag_Matrix_sum(int (&Matrix)[rows][columns])
{
    // ...
```

Place this function before `main` so you do not need a prototype. `All_Matrix_sum` needs a similar fix.

To make your code easier to read, consider using range-based for-loops, or even better, standard algorithms such as `std::accumulate` for summing a range.  The algorithm in `Diag_matrix_sum` could be much simplified, you only need one loop.

Comment: sorry i am a beginner so this is somehow hard to understand!!
Anyways, appreciate your great reply and thanks again

Comment: the word prototype is really hard to understand, what i found from my little google search is that prototype is the type of the function !! is that true ??!

Comment: "prototype" is another word for function declaration ; all functions must be declared before they are called

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. M.M, really appreciate your great effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is edited version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* If your function parameter is array then you must declare 
And if you are using other than 1D array, you need to specify the dimension(s)
*/

int All_Matrix_sum( int[][3], int, int);  
int Diag_Matrix_sum( int[][3], int, int); 

int main (){
    int My_Matrix[5][3];
    for(int i=0; i <5 ; i++){
        for (int y=0; y <3; y++){
            cout << "Please enter the Value corresponds to the position of " << i << ", " << y << endl;
            cin >> My_Matrix[i][y]; // get values from the user
            }
        }
    cout << "the sumation of all the matrix elements is : " << All_Matrix_sum(My_Matrix, 5 , 3 );
    cout << "the sumation of the matrix's diagonal is : "<<   Diag_Matrix_sum(My_Matrix, 5 , 3 );
}



int Diag_Matrix_sum(int Matrix[][3], int rows, int columns){ // this method calculates the sumation of the diagonal elements
    int sumD=0;
    for(int Row_numbers=0; Row_numbers <rows; Row_numbers++){
        for (int Column_numbers=0; Column_numbers <columns; Column_numbers++){
            if(Column_numbers==Row_numbers)
            sumD += Matrix[Row_numbers][Column_numbers];
            }
        }
    return sumD;
}


int All_Matrix_sum(int Matrix[][3], int rows, int columns){ // this method calculates the sumation of all the elements in such a matrix
    int sumA=0;
    for(int Row_numbers=0; Row_numbers <rows; Row_numbers++){
        for (int Column_numbers=0; Column_numbers <columns; Column_numbers++){
            sumA += Matrix[Row_numbers][Column_numbers];
            }
        }
    return sumA;
}
```

Comment: @AhmedSayed, note the comment: If your function parameter is array then you must declare 
    And if you are using other than 1D array, you need to specify the dimension(s)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is really clear and helpful!!

Comment: @AhmedSayed if it is helpful then, don't forget to accept this answer so that in future others will find the helpful answer easily.